# What technology can be used for this browserbased ping-pong game?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, actionscript-3, browser

I just saw the McDonald's commercial which I have linked to below and I would like to try developing something similar for a festival. We have been talking about making a game in which the user has to use their iPhone and something like what McDonald's has done would be great.

My question is if anyone have an idea how I can send the data and what technology they might have used? I imagine making two websites. One on which the game itself is shown and one which is the controller but how would I make sure that the data is sent and handled fast enough?

I am familiar with JavaScript and PHP. I have been working a bit with flash and ActionScript and I am wondering if that might be best for the game (obviously not the controller)

You can see the McDonald's commercial on the link below. Basically, the user visits a webpage which is the controller and then they are able to play the ping-pong game on the big screen.

Any ideas and brainstorming on how to do this is welcome.

[Watch the McDonald's Pick n Play commercial here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u0ij9D5S4Y)

Comment: For real time connections between sites use websockets.

Comment: How cool is that? I wanna play.

Comment: @Raynos I have decided to use websockets. It seems the smartest and it is definately in realtime. I'm not sure what people normally do on these forums but as I am using your approach, maybe you should make an answer which I can accept? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/). The problem with them is browser support and supporting older browsers / platforms.

To handle this there are various abstractions. I would personally recommend [socket.io](http://socket.io/) A solid abstraction that relies on [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Has a range of fallbacks (including COMET and Flash). Whilst your at it, you might want to looking into using node for realtime applications (it's great!)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a socket server that hosts the game (socket TCP/IP connection). The purpose of the socket server application would be to listen for connections, wait for 2 players, start the game, decide who wins and sett-era (it could also have some queue of players that will play next and inform the players where they are in the queue).

Now, how do we establish a connection from the website to that socket server?

I wouldn't use WebSockets because it's not widely supported at the moment, disabled by default in FireFox and IE does not have it implemented yet (AFAIK).

Now you have to decide, do you want to do the website in Flash or HTML. You could even use  hybrid of both. For example:

**Hybrid:** 
Use the Flash application on the controller website to act as the communicator between JavaScript and the server. When Flash retrieves data from the socket server then it will make JavaScript take care of the retrieved command. E.g. move pad up. (I use that method for my online chat application and it works like a charm).

**Flash only:**
Use pure Flash application as the controller and communicator to the socket server.

Voila! You have something similar to the MacDonalds game.

I hope my answer is clear enough and feel free to comment if some of my statements are wrong.

Comment: Well, Flash is not really an option for the controller as there are smartphones who does not support it (I'm having the iPhone in mind). For WebSockets, it is not something I have yet worked with but I am reading up on it right now. It seems that is has become widely supported (even by Safari in iOS 4.2)

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'm really looking forward to using WebSockets but I've just heard so many downsides due to security issues involved. For example FireFox has it disabled by default because of security issues involved. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could also use send the data via HTTP, but I'm just unsure how fast it can be. E.g. when moving the pad would require sending maybe 10-20 commands very quickly so it wont lag behind on the screen. But this is as far as my knowledge goes, good luck!

Comment: @SimonBS use abstractions for websockets like [socket.io](http://socket.io/). This uses websockets natively where available then falls back on COMET or flash depending on what you prefer.

Comment: @Raynos The problem I see with COMET is that it's good at getting response in an effective way, but not sending data. Sending data would mean you'd just do a normal HTTP request right?

Comment: @raRaRa yes. You have to use HTTP to send data. You also use HTTP to receive data. Without websockets (TCP), Flash (TCP) or Java (TCP/UDP) you have to use HTTP. (I think SL also has some kind of TCP)

Answer (score 0):

In my view, This is what I would go for :

A small client app that will be downloaded when connected to the website.Considering it in mobile platform, java app preferably. Alternative is flash, which is also suitable, but if graphics is not our aim then I suppose better hold it off.

A server to provide real time connections to the users one-at-a-time. (As shown in video). This is the actual pain for all the games out there. I would go looking for one of these projects as platforms:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

http://www.cubeia.org/

http://appengine.google.com/

Besides that, ideas - I would have liked if it was multi player (there was quite a crowd), but that would have meant at least person winning every game & more of free give aways for them.

Comment: They specifically say at the linked site that you don't have to download an app. Having to download and install an app would 1) delay the user being able to start playing 2) turn away users with phones where the app doesn't work for some reason and 3) not be attractive to security-conscious users cautious about downloading unknown apps. Sure you trust McDonald's, but how do you even know it's really them?

Answer (score 0):

As alternative can be **COMET** a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a **web server to push data to a browser**, without the browser explicitly requesting it

have a look here: [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: I don't really see how COMET helps. Basically the phone is not getting any response of the game, everything happens on the screen. It's a question about how you send the data so COMET is not really an answer to this problem. It's the same as saying "Use HTTP to send the data".

Comment: Everything happen on the screen ? Oh no, you have to send data and request data via HTTP to update your screen with the new status. And the question request not use flash because Iphone not support it, so a stream HTTP is needed to keep the connection and transfer data IN & OUT. Comet do that, keep a session alive using the HTTP only.